# Does operator overloading still cause performance hit for SIMD wrappers?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, simd

I was reading: http://jmabille.github.io/blog/2014/11/20/performance-considerations-about-simd-wrappers/

That blog says that operator overloading for simd wrapper introduces overhead when the code is compiled with gcc 4.7.3.

Is this still true for new gcc (like gcc 5 or 6) or intel c compilers (2016 version)?

In Agner Fog's [vector class library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/), it seems the operations (such as >) is defined by the stateless function as described in the blog.

Comment: The link you have provided says: "To conclude, operators overloads don’t prevent the compiler to reorder instructions during optimization, and thus they don’t introduce any performance issue.", unless I'm looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @Tristan Brindle. You are right, sorry that I made a mistake when I read that blog. The cause was the crtp layer.

Comment: In my experience looking at compiler output, wrapper classes / functions (including overloaded operators) do inline and optimize away entirely.